Jensen's inequality on (super)operator exponential
Let us define the expectation value $\langle A\rangle_{\rho}$ of a superoperator $A$ over a density matrix $\rho$ as $(\rho, A(\rho))$, where the scalar product between operators reads $(O_1,O_2):= Tr[O_1^+ O_2]$.
Is it true that:
$$
|\langle e^{\mathcal{L} t} \rangle_{\rho}|^2 \geq |e^{\langle\mathcal{L}\rangle_{\rho} t}|^2,
$$
where the expected value is taken over a generic physical state $\rho$?
I am mostly interested in the case where $\mathcal{L}$ is the lindbladian superoperator, but is there some operator Jensen's inequality that justifies (a variant of) the above inequality?

How do you define the expectation value of a quantum channel, resp. of a Hermitian-preserving linear map? Even after specifying a [generic physical] state $\rho$ it is still not clear to me what $\langle e^{\mathcal L t}\rangle_\rho$ is supposed to mean.

@FrederikvomEnde Well, you could take the convex mixture of all $e^{\mathcal L t}$. What is less clear to me is what $\ge$ is supposed to mean in that case.

I would define $\langle A\rangle_{\rho}:= Tr[\rho A(\rho)]=(\rho, A(\rho))$, where the scalar product (•,•) is defined as $(A,B)=Tr[A^{+} B]$.

@lgotta This does not explain what you mean by the averages in the question above. Could you please clarify? Also, what is the meaning of $\ge$ in the context of superoperators?

I edited the notation above. I am asking whether the above inequality holds for an arbitrary density matrix $\rho$ over which the average is taken. As for the inequality sign, I guess that the problem is that on both sides one has complex numbers; then I would put the absolute value on both sides.

Please add all required definitions to the question itself.

Thanks for the link! The problem here is that in the case of a Lindbladian superoperator, the expectation value is not real. So does Jensen's inequality hold with the absolute value on both
sides for operators with complex expectation values?

Why do you care about this question?

@NorbertSchuch  I asked about it because I was looking for a lower bound to the decay of the l.h.s. (the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product of $\rho(0)$ with $\rho(t)$) via the the r.h.s.. This because the exponent in the r.h.s. $\langle \mathcal{L}\rangle_{\rho}$ might vanish in the thermodynamic limit for some special states $\rho$ that are in some way ''continuously connected'' to a (pure) stationary state in the large-size limit, thus freezing the l.h.s. to 1.

Makes sense to see if you can find a counterexample in that class.

Substituting your definition you are asking whether for all Lindbladians $\mathcal L$, all times $t\geq 0$, and all reference states $\rho$ it holds that
$$
{\rm tr}(\rho e^{t\mathcal L}(\rho))\geq e^{t\,{\rm tr}(\rho \mathcal L(\rho))}\,.\tag1
$$
Before giving a counterexample I want to point out that Eq. (1) already makes sense without the absolute value assuming $\mathcal L$ is Hermitian-preserving ($\mathcal L(X)^\dagger=\mathcal L(X^\dagger)$ for all $X$), which all Lindbladians and all quantum channels satisfy. The reasoning here is that both $\mathcal L(\rho)$ and $e^{t\mathcal L}(\rho)$ being Hermitian guarantees that all expressions are real because the trace of a product of Hermitian matrices is always real. So the only scenario you'd need an absolute value is when $\mathcal L$ is a "generic" linear map that does not preserve Hermiticity.
As for the counterexample, start from an arbitrary Lindbladian $\mathcal L$ and remember that $\mathcal L$ will admit a stationary state, i.e. some $\rho$ such that $\mathcal L(\rho)=0$, cf. Proposition 5 in this paper (arXiv). Now if Eq. (1) were true for this pair $(\mathcal L,\rho)$, then
$$
{\rm tr}(\rho^2)={\rm tr}(\rho e^{t\mathcal L}(\rho))\geq e^{t\,{\rm tr}(\rho \mathcal L(\rho))}=e^{t\cdot 0}=1\,.\tag2
$$
So the only way for this to be true is that $\rho$ is a pure state; in other words picking any Lindbladian with a non-pure stationary state Eq. (1) will be wrong. (P.S. If you insist on keeping the absolute value square in the original question, then this argument of course still holds)

Thank you for the very clean answer! It would be nice to know if it holds on all states but the stationary ones, if you have any idea about that I can open a new question with this twist to the problem. Have a nice day!

While the inequality is wrong for short times for all non-pure states (set t=0 in Eq.(1)) some numerics suggest that for pure states $\rho$ and purely dissipative Lindbladians (i.e. no Hamiltonian) your inequality seems to hold for all times? And if you only care about sufficiently long times then Eq.(1) seems to be true for all Lindbladians and all pure states $\rho$? What is for sure is that the pure case is neither obviously true nor obviously false—so this'd certainly be a question worth asking if this special case interests you!
